# Visual effect View for entire window using swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

I tried to create an app with this style:

[image: Calculator.app in macOS]

I used a visual effect view in Interface Builder to achieve this:

[image: the visual effect view is not visible under the title bar]

Is it possible to also apply the visual effect view to the title bar using Swift 4 and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to `Storyboard` select `Window` open `Attribute inspector` and check `Full Size Content View`

[image]